# Query on populated field in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

How can I set this condition in my mongoose query?
Note that coinId is a populated field

```
signalModel
    .find(
        {
            'coinId.Price': { $gt: 1000 }
        },
        (err, signals) => {
            if (err) throw err
            res.json(signals)
        }
    )
    .populate('coinId')
```

**Update:**

I tried this query from the answers, but I didn't satisfied with the result since the coin field is an empty array.

```
let signals = await signalModel.aggregate([
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: 'Coin',
            localField: 'coinId',
            foreignField: '_id',
            as: 'coin'
        }
    },
    {
        $match: {
            type: req.query.type ?? /^(buy|sell)$/i,
            'coin.Price': { $gt: 1000 }
        }
    }
])
```

The result:

```
{
    "_id": "616eb8d2c31a52512900f56b",
    "coinId": "616e8c07ca518ef7fac3eea9",
    "type": "buy",
    "highEntryPoint": 60000,
    "lowEntryPoint": 59500,
    "stopLoss": 59000,
    "takeProfit": 60500,
    "lastPrice": 61998.1102423889,
    "status": "waiting",
    "__v": 0,
    "coin": []
}
```

**Update2**

Input Example/Signal

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("616eb8d2c31a52512900f56b"),
"coinId" : ObjectId("616e8c07ca518ef7fac3eea9"),
"type" : "buy",
"highEntryPoint" : 60000,
"lowEntryPoint" : 59500,
"stopLoss" : 59000,
"takeProfit" : 60500,
"lastPrice" : 61998.1102423889,
"status" : "waiting",
"__v" : 0
}
```

Input Example/Coin

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("616e8c07ca518ef7fac3eea9"),
"Name" : "BTC",
"Price" : 61700.9584311177,
"__v" : 0
}
```

Comment: Can you add an example of input data? And the expected output

Comment: @J.F.  updated. In this case, I want the signal to be returned because the price of its coin is greater than 1000

Answer (score 0):

first use `$lookup` then add condition in aggregate like this :

```
signalModel.aggregate([
{$lookup:{
from: 'Coins' // coins collection name
localField: coindId,
foreignField: _id
as: coins
}},
{
  $match:{'coins':{$ne: []}}
 }
,{
$match :{"coins.Price":{$gt:1000}}
}
])
```

Comment: Seems close but didn't get the answer yet. Please read the updates

Comment: could you add sampe input data

Comment: so we could check if coinId is not empty

Comment: I update my answer